# HOW TO HIDE TOOLBAR IN MAGENTO 2?

Tags: magento2, toolbar

[image]

SOLUTION : user this code 
what is the best solution : for that is this correct or is there any other solution

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `remove="true"` if you don't want it on the page. 
Check the difference between remove and display attributes at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar can be Removed by commenting in the current theme directory.

```
app/design/frontend/Package/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Comment code at 2 places in the file.

```
<?php //echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

As you want to hide for certain category , hide it for category_id

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

if($category->getId()!=13){
 echo $block->getToolbarHtml() 
}
```

Say your category id is 13, so it will not be displayed in case of it.